# Getting <identifier> expected illegal start of type error in a timer function

Tags: java, timer, timertask

This is my first time posting so please forgive me if I am doing this wrong.  This has been working perfectly but when I put the code in to call the audio it gets the error  expected illegal start of type error.  I just moved the exact syntax from another class where it worked fine.

Any ideas?

Sorry to put in so much code but I wanted you to see the context.  It's inside of a timer now whereas it wasn't in the other class (file).

The line you are looking for is about 55 lines down in the code and says "GETTING  expected illegal start of type error" in the comment above it.

Thanks!!!

CODE STARTS HERE

```
package boom;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class Countdown extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form Countdown
 */   

public Countdown() {
    initComponents();
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    int xsize = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth();
    int ysize = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight();
    this.setSize(xsize, ysize);



    Timer timer = new Timer(); //new timer


    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {  
        //counter countIn = new counter();

        //GET COUNTER ENTERED FROM MainMenu and saved in...
        int count1 = counter.counter2.getCounter();

        //Play Countdown
        //TODO: GETTING <identifier> expected illegal start of type error
        PlayAudio.playAudio("AudioFiles/15before.wav");


        String readableText;
        String secondsDisplay;
        String minutesDisplay;

        public void run() { 

            //COUNTDOWN LOGIC
            int minutes = count1/60;
            int seconds = count1%60;

            //convert countdown to readable
            minutesDisplay = Integer.toString(minutes);

            if (seconds >9){
                secondsDisplay = Integer.toString(seconds);
            } else {
                secondsDisplay = "0"+ Integer.toString(seconds);
            }

            readableText = minutesDisplay + ":" + secondsDisplay;

            //send countdown text to label
            countdownLabel.setText(readableText);




            count1 --;
            if (count1 == -1){
                timer.cancel();                                       
            } //else if(isIt){
               // timer.cancel();
               // isIt = false;
           // }

            }

    };

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000); // =  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, period);



}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    countdownLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    goToKeypadButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));

    countdownLabel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    countdownLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Monospaced", 0, 96)); // NOI18N
    countdownLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 51));
    countdownLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

    goToKeypadButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    goToKeypadButton.setText("Show Keypad");
    goToKeypadButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            goToKeypadButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(goToKeypadButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(countdownLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 448, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(15, 15, 15)
            .addComponent(countdownLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 221, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(goToKeypadButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    countdownLabel.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void goToKeypadButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    this.setVisible(false);
    new Keypad().setVisible(true);
}                                                

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Countdown.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Countdown.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Countdown.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Countdown.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Countdown().setVisible(true);


        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel countdownLabel;
private javax.swing.JButton goToKeypadButton;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: The line you are looking for starts with:  PlayAudio.playAudio

Comment: Please check your brace pairs. Code formatting helps a lot with that

Comment: Thanks, but no I don't think that's it.  There is only the one line (51) that causes the error.  When I comment it out it runs fine.  And it's literally cut and pasted from another class.  The only difference I can work out is it is in a different place.  It is very puzzling.  I did look at the output and saw it says "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Method "<error>" in class boom/Countdown$1 has illegal signature "(LfileName;)Lboom/PlayAudio$playAudio;" but it's the same signature and method as before XP